Spyders variable explorer not functioning properly after upgrade to Spyder 6.0
After upgrading to Spyder 6.0, I am not able to open and inspect simple variables like lists from the variable explorer. I recieve:

Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console.
The error message was:
An error occured, see the console.
Note: Please don't report this problem on Github, there's nothing to do about it.

I have encountered this problem with earlier Spyder versions too, but only for complex objects that could not be displayed. Unfortunately, this change makes Spyder 6.0 not usable in its current form.
I was not able to find a report for this problem which is specific to Spyder 6.0 (and the accompanying spyder-kernel=3.0) and I am lost for clues, as the console is not printing any error messages. Any ideas how to fix this?

it would potentially be helpful if you could add some details of your environment, e.g. operating system, Python version, how you installed Spyder.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and I have installed Spyder via Anaconda. For Python, I am using 3.12.
